# Slide issues in WordPress site (RoyalSlider & Revolution Slider)

Tags: wordpress, slide

I'm having problems to insert slides in my WordPress site. I tried with two plugins, Revolution Slider and RoyalSlider, but it happens the same with the two of them, they generate the lists to show the slide but the images don't appear.

Links to the website: 
http://ubsitios.info/silviafotos/gallery/asia/
http://ubsitios.info/silviafotos/gallery/europa/

What can be the problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have Javascript errors which are stopping the sliders working.  In general.js you have;

```
jQuery( ".featured, .post, .widget, .panel" ).fitVids();
```

This method fitVids() is undefined and therefore there is an error thrown.  Fix that and take it from there, you can view JS errors in the console of Chrome's developer tools or Firebug.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I could fix the problem in another way.

Comment: Can you please add your solution here if you fixed it?